# A burning sensation

Tags: riddle, word, limerick

What's the burning sensation in the following Limerick?

```
 Complete, I'm a burning sensation,  
 Less my second, provide information,  
    Then curtailed, an offense  
    Like the one with the quince,  
 And beheaded, a doctor's location.
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The burning sensation is

> a 'sting'.
>  Remove the second letter to get 'sing', which means provide information (what a criminal might do, to the police).
>  When 'sing' is curtailed (has the last letter removed), we get 'sin', which is an offense. An example is Adam and Eve's decision to eat the forbidden fruit from the tree of knowledge, and some say the fruit was a quince.
>  Finally, 'sin' is beheaded to give 'in', and "The doctor is in" is a common expression.